# Two IP addresses on same computer

Tags: networking

### Two ip addresses on same computer and switch behavior

Say I assign two IP addresses to same network card.  Since there is only one network card, there is only one MAC address.  If some other computer sends message to that MAC address, how does the switch send traffic to the right receiver?  Does host with two IP addresses register the same MAC address with two IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 2 IP addresses can be associated with a single MAC address.

When a computer on a lan wants tp communicate with a computer whise mac address it does not know it broadcasts an ARP request asking "who has address ww.xx.yy.zz".  The MAC address that knows it says " I do".  **There is nothing preventing a computer responding for multiple IP addresses and providing the MAC associated with the interface.

Answer (score 0):

[Switches](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) operate on the [Ethernet](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) Layer. They don't even know about the [Internet Protocol](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol).

More precisely, switches operate on the [*Medium Access Control (MAC) layer*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_access_control) of [IEEE 802.3-2022](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3).

The switch only knows about [MAC addresses](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), so it makes its decision which frames to send to which ports purely based on MAC addresses.

Note: there are so-called "[Layer 3 switches](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_switch)" in the market. But that is only a marketing term. On a technical level, those aren't switches, they are [*routers*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)).

Comment: Layer 3 switches share stuff in common with routers, but they are not routers - ie the difference is more then a marketting term.  , They are not as general purpose as routers- farming out a limited set of layer 3 requirements in hardware.  They don't typically handle VPN's, DHCP, NAT or a lot of other router functionality.  They are more a hybrid between a switch and a cut down router.

Comment: VPN has nothing to do with a router. That's the job of a VPN server. Of course, it makes sense to run a VPN server on a router, and many routers have VPN servers built in. But so do many L3 switches. The one I am looking at supports 576 400G interfaces and can run IPSec at line-rate on every single of them simultaneously for a total throughput of 230 Tbps. DHCP is the job of a DHCP server, not a router. Again, it makes total sense to run a DHCP server on a router, but that doesn't mean that DHCP is part of the functionality of a router. …

Comment: … And I haven't seen an L3 switch that doesn't come with a DHCP server. The one I'm looking at right now comes with a modified version of Kea pre-installed. It also supports DHCP Relay and DHCP Snooping. Also, the L3 switch I am looking at supports SNAT, DNAT, and Dynamic SNAT. Some models support sophisticated packet rewriting that goes far beyond standard NAT.